# pmax function on lists of lists

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-lists

I have some lists stored in lists. The third level contains a vector with numeric values and some NAs.

I want to use pmax to find the highest value between two vectors that have the same position.

```
pmax(low_all_res[[1]][[1]][[1]], high_all_res[[1]][[1]][[1]])
```

This works and outputs a list. But I want to do so for a lot of lists with different indices. Basically I want to compare low_all_res and high_all_res and get the highest value from between them.

My data structure looks like this:

```
low_all_res[[1:5]][[1:5]][[1:10]]
```

And it is the lists in the last list I want to compare between low and high.

I then tried:

```
comb_all_res <- list()
for (k in 1:5){
  for(m in 1:5){
    for (i in 1:10){
      comb_all_res[[k]][[m]][[i]] <- pmax(low_all_res[[k]][[m]][[i]], high_all_res[[k]][[m]][[i]]) 
}}}

Error in `*tmp*`[[k]] : subscript out of bounds
```

But get the error as shown.

I have also tried an approach with temporary files, but I think I use the wrong indexing operators for the tmp files. This code looks like this, but I have tried a lot of different approaches. The code works, but I only get results for the last 10 vectors.

```
comb_all_res <- list()
tmp_low <- list()
tmp_high <- list()
tmp_low2 <- list()
tmp_high2 <- list()

for (i in 1:10){

  for (k in 1:5){

  tmp_low <- low_all_res[[k]]
  tmp_high <- high_all_res[[k]]

    for(m in 1:5){

    tmp_low2 <- tmp_low[[m]] 
    tmp_high2 <- tmp_high[[m]]

    comb_all_res[[i]] <- pmax(tmp_low2[[i]], tmp_high2[[i]])

}}}
```

Can anybody critique my code, so I can get it straight?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible example (e.g. some lists)?

Comment: This is wrong from the get-go just by inspection: `low_all_res[[1:5]][[1:5]][[1:10]]`. The "[[" function does not accept vectors with more than one element. So that cannot possibly be your data and you need to post  an example with code that would not throw an error.

Comment: I'm new to Stackexchange. I just used the 1:5 to show that there is 5 elements. It is a nested list. List 1 has 5 elements, that are lists with each 5 elements that are in a tree like structure. My data is in the end of that tree. and are 10 vectors with numbers (I tried to show that with the 1:10 in the end). I'll provide some example code tomorrow because I am not sure exactly how to do this right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
# Some fake data:
set.seed(123)
list_1 <- list(list(list(1:5), list(rep(3,5)), list(sample(1:10, 5))), list(list(sample(10:15)), list(rep(10,5)), list(sample(100:110, 5))))
list_2 <- list(list(list(5:1), list(rep(5,5)), list(sample(10:1, 5))), list(list(sample(15:10)), list(rep(20,5)), list(sample(1000:110, 5))))

pmax(unlist(list_1), unlist(list_2))
 [1]   5   4   3   4   5   5   5   5   5   5   8  10   4   7   6  11  12  13  14  15  15  20  20
[24]  20  20  20 471 743 870 145 200
```

To put the results into a list of similar structure as the original lists you can do the following (thanks to Ananda Mahto who [helped to find `relist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180352/replace-all-values-of-a-recursive-list-with-values-of-a-vector)):

```
relist(pmax(unlist(list_1), unlist(list_2)), skeleton = list_1)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 5 4 3 4 5


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 5 5 5 5 5


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1]  8 10  4  7  6



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 15


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 20 20 20 20 20


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 471 743 870 145 200
```

Comment: BTW: your `mapply` is not needed, `pmax(unlist(list_1), unlist(list_2))` is enough.

Comment: This is what I want. And I can get the pmax function to work. What I cannot do is to store the results in another list with the same structure. Perhaps I should have used dataframes with factors instead. But, alas for now I'm stuck with lists because I've learnt that if you need 25 consecutive numbered dataframes, it is better to use lists. I'm pretty new to this kind of modelling. I have basically, 250 datasets. I put them in 5 lists depending on what I have done with them. Each of these 5 lists consist of further 5 lists with 10 lists in the,

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer did exactly what I wanted.